# Disabling previously searched term suggestion in a search bar

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, css

I was following this tutorial:
http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/a_fancy_apple.com-style_search_suggestion.html

And checking out the demo here:
http://qpoit.com/marcofolio_demo/apple_search/

I realized something.

If you take a particular search term, like iPhone for example, and type that into the demo search bar and hit the return key.

Then, upon placing your cursor once again into the search bar, and typing the letter i, it will bring up a suggestion for the keyword "iPhone", because, obviously, the end-user has searched for that keyword before.

I was wondering if there was a way to eliminate that, or if that's just browser functionality, and it must be worked around, because in my opinion, it gets in the way of the design..

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the attribute `autocomplete="off"` in your tag.